# How can I invoke ms paint using a ruby program to open multiple files?

Tags: ruby

I have observed that the below code helps to invoke mspaint for a specific file :

```
print("mspaint  #{%x{mspaint c:/image/a.jpg}}")#
```

I have a number of JPG files within the folder : D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics
And, I would like to open each file in MS PAINT within a for loop. The code below throws a pop error saying that Paint does not locate D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/files[i].png !

```
for i in 2..(@files.size-1)
puts(@files[i] + " #{File.size(@files[i])} bytes")  
print("mspaint  #{%x{mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/files[i]}}")
```

How can I achieve this ? Further to this, how can I automate actions within MS PAINT - for example, clicking the resize button in PAINT ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues but the main problem is:

```
%x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/files[i] }
```

The contents for `%x{}` are the same as a string inside double-quotes. It's possible to interpolate variables into that string, but they have to use `#{...}` markers surrounding the variable.

The above line could be written:

```
%x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/#{ files[i] } }
```

However, that doesn't result in code that is easy to understand, which leads to problems when doing maintenance. Instead, I'd write:

```
print("mspaint  #{ %x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/files[i] } }")
```

differently.

Meditate on this instead:

```
output = `%x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/#{ files[i] }`
print("mspaint #{ output }")
```

Instead of multiple nested braces (`{...}`), they're unraveled a bit for readability. There's no reason to jam everything into one line; It doesn't speed up the processing of the code, and it certainly hurts readability and long-term maintainability, so be kind to your eyes and brain, and those in others who might follow in your footsteps reading the code.

But, there's more: Don't use `for i in 2..(@files.size-1)`. It's too convoluted, and, `for` leaves `i` behind to clutter the namespace for no reason. Instead use:

```
@files[2 .. -1].each do |i|
```

and

```
output = `%x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/#{ i }`
```

`each` does the same thing, but contains the local variable `i` inside the block so it can be discarded after the block exits. It also avoids the whole `(@files.size-1)` rigamarole of playing with indexes because `i` now contains the value itself not the index. Trying to walk the elements via an index is the source of innumerable index-off-the-end-of-the-array errors in various languages. In Ruby we don't do that because we've got a better way, so use `each` instead.

Combining those things results in:

```
@files[2..-1].each do |i|
  output = `%x{ mspaint D:/Users/d682707/Desktop/Fotos/Frankston/Pics/#{ i }`
  print("mspaint #{ output }")
end
```